# CoolStorage can't set One-To-One relationship

Tags: orm, one-to-one, coolstorage

The issue is that I can't understand how to make a OneToOne relation between two objects the way for the first object to have a link to the second and for the second to have a link to the first. Here's the code:

```
[MapTo("Model")]
public class Model : CSObject<Model, int>
{
    [OneToOne(LocalKey = "ModelID", ForeignKey = "ModelID")]
    public Product Product { get { return (Product)GetField ("Product"); } set { SetField ("Product", value); } } 
}

[MapTo("Product")]
public class Product : CSObject<Product, int>
{
    [OneToOne(LocalKey = "ProductID", ForeignKey = "ProductID")]
    public Model Model { get { return (Model)GetField ("Model"); } set { SetField ("Model", value); } }
}
```

The thing is that when I create a product and a model and set the model's property "Product" to the created one and save it, the product's "Model" property doesn't get set and remains NULL. I've already tried making all the local and foreign keys for both Product's and Model's properties the same (e.g. "ModelID") but it didn't solve the problem. What is the right way of doing this?

I guess making one of them `[OneToMany]` will do the trick but will return a collection while I need a single object to be returned by a property.

**Update**

Here comes a simple solution one would call a crutch:

```
[OneToMany]
public CSList<Product> _ProductList { get { return (CSList<Product>)GetField ("_ProductList"); } set { SetField ("_ProductList", value); } }

[NotMapped]
public Product Product {
    get {
        CSList<Product> list = this._ProductList;
        if (list.Count > 0)
            return list [0];
        return null;
    }
    set {
        if (value != null) {
            CSList<Product> list = this._ProductList;
            list.RemoveAll ();
            list.Add (value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make both relations [ManyToOne]. That will work in your scenario.

Comment: I'm afraid, this will not work. ManyToOne pattern implies having a column held in the table which is "Many" holding id of "One". That means that we must have a ProductID column in the Model table and vice versa. When we set Product's Model property to some model, we update Product table's column "ModelID", but the Model table's "ProductID" column remains untouched. Moreover such approach may cause errors when trying to save as it seems to be an infinite cycle.